# <video> tag not working inside QtWebkit on windows

Tags: qt, html, webkit, qtwebkit

I can't seem to get an html video tag to play in QtWebkit. It shows up as a blue square with a question mark, like an unsupported plugin. Flash videos play fine, and HTML5 canvas works great.

Specs:

OS: Windows 7

Qt: 4.6.3 (installed from the qt creator 2.0.1 from nokia's site)

PySide: 0.4 (latest)

QtWebit configuration (I tried all kinds of combinations, now I have): PluginsEnabled, LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, JavascriptEnabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem seemed that the default Qt + PySide installation is broken. It couldn't find the Qt plugins or the phonon backends.
When I swithced to using PyQt it worked. It could be made usable with the Qt from nokia and PySide but it will require more work and playing around with the paths. To see the bug just use Process Monitor and see how Qt can't find backends and plugins.